# How to use web3 to buy ERC20 USDT

Tags: web3js, erc-20, usdt, tether

We are looking to allow our users to buy/sell USDT-ERC.

I am confused about how this process works. Initially thought they could just allow them to buy/sell directly using web3 and the USDT ERC20 contract. It seems you can't do this as there is no function to buy.

Now I am thinking we need to buy USDT-ERC into our own master ETH address and then use that mater address to allow our users to buy/sell. Would this be the correct way?

How can we buy USDT-ERC into our own master ETH address?

Comment: There's no buy or sell, this process has to be implemented outside of the token contract. Once you found a seller (an address with enough token) and that you agreed on the price, you can use your own contract to deal or whatever mean to pay and then the seller will call the transfer function on the token contract to send some to you.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what's USDT-ERC, but if you want users to be able to buy or sell USDT with ETH as the base currency, the easiest option is to embed Uniswap on your website:

https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/interface-integration/iframe-integration/